# Nutritional information on fruits and veggies

Tags: vegetables, fruit, nutrient-composition

I've been looking online for an extensive database of nutritional information on various fruits and vegetables. I've been advised by my doctor to start eating healthier and I'd just like to know the calories, vitamins and minerals that each type of fruit and vegetable have.

I'd like to use the chart in making more salads, vegetable and fruit side dishes and the like ... I just need to know what's good to use and what type of vegetable and fruit provides what type of nutrition.

I've tried searching on google but my google-fu appears to be missing the mark this time, most of the stuff I've found only lists a few fruits and veggies or has little information for each item. I'd like a comprehensive list so I can change things up as I cook and not get stuck in the same ol rut (an apple a day is good and all but gets boring after a while).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first-line reference is: http://nutritiondata.self.com/

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer a slightly Zen answer. The best thing to do is not to count nutrients in your food, trying to reach some "correct" number.

The trick is simply to eat more food that is home-made or fresh, and less processed food. Particularly, go for leafy greens, fun fruit and whole grains.

There is little benefit in worrying whether you're getting enough molybdenum or not.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't be aware and interested in the nutritional values of different foodstuffs, just don't take it *too* seriously.

Answer (score 1):

You can find quite an extensive list in some cookbooks.
In general, there are more calories in fruits than in vegetables.
Vegetables with a lot of water (cucumber, lettuce...) are very low in calories.

[Here](http://www.weightlossforall.com/calories-fruit.htm) is some info on fruit, and [here](http://www.weightlossresources.co.uk/calories/calorie_counter/fruit.htm) some more.

I think you can eat all veggies you want, as much as you like.
If you are on a diet, I wouldn't eat bananas and nuts.

[This](http://www.weightlossforall.com/low-calorie-food-list.htm) is a list with food which is low in calories.
Keep in mind that bread is 'better' than pasta or potatoes.

Comment: @Mein thank you ! ... not really on a "low calorie" diet per se .. just a change in my diet ... trying to eat healthier ... getting off the fried foods and fast foods ... going for more vitamins and minerals

Comment: Oh, I wasn't sure :) You can eat all veggies/fruits then. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the accumulated data on http://dailyburn.com/. There you can also keep track of your daily intake.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to online resources, there are many softwares (diet planners, calories counters, even some recipe managers) that could help you finding nutritional information and tracking your calories intake.

From a quick google search I've found [this one](http://www.dietsindetails.com/software.html) that could suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://caloriecount.about.com. I used it for ages and it does a lot more than count calories. You can search for food nutrition, log food you eat, set targets and it can analyse what you ate.

Their analysis tells you which nutirants you are eatting a lot of and which are missing from your diet. It will even let you click on a nutirent on your report, say [potassium](http://caloriecount.about.com/potassium-facts-nf306#highfoods) (which I apparently don't get enough of) and will give a list of things you could eat to do better

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha has quite a lot of [nutritional data](http://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/FoodAndNutrition.html) and can create mock nutritional labels.

[image: Reuben Sandwich]
[image: Reuben Sandwich]

<sup><sub>I used the default quantities. You can set them for each ingredient. The photograph from Wikipedia obviously has more of everything.</sub></sup>